# How to change the eclipse osgi service to timeout

Tags: eclipse, osgi

I need to debug through the start of an OSGi dynamic service in Eclipse RCP application but the timeout is too short (or I'm too slow at debugging!).

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.ds 2 0 2015-02-25 21:46:26.374
!MESSAGE Getting a lock required more than 10000 ms. There might be a synchronization problem in this callstack or just the build/dispose process of some components took too long!
```

Is there a way to set the timeout value to longer than the default 10000?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like this can be configured in the debugging '.options' file for 'org.eclipse.equinox.ds' plugin:

```
# Debugging options for the org.eclipse.equinox.ds plugin

# Turns on/off debugging of SCR
org.eclipse.equinox.ds/debug=true
# Specifies that logged entries should be printed to the framework runtime console 
org.eclipse.equinox.ds/print_on_console=false
# Enables generating and printing logs about the time performance of the operations executed by the SCR
org.eclipse.equinox.ds/performance=false
# Makes instance of each component nevertheless components are "immediate" or not
org.eclipse.equinox.ds/instantiate_all=false

#Advanced options 
# Enables caching of the parsed XML documents of the component descriptions
#org.eclipse.equinox.ds/cache_descriptions=false
# Specifies the maximum time in milliseconds, which is allowed to a user component's activate or bind method to take. If the method invocation has not finished, a new dispatcher thread will be launched to process the pending work of SCR 
org.eclipse.equinox.ds/block_timeout=30000
```

To use this file specify `-debug <path to options file>` on the eclipse command.

Answer (score 1):

You could also set a *VM argument* if you start the eclipse instance with *run configuration*

```
-Dequinox.ds.block_timeout=300000000
```

Answer (score 0):

To increase the Time have a look at Equinox/RuntimeOptions:

http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox/RuntimeOptions

For example:

-Dequinox.scr.waitTimeOnBloc=15000